# numbers representable as sums of perfect powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

Here is my little research:

$4=2^2$

$8=2^3$

$9=3^2$

$12=2^3+2^2$

$13=3^2+2^2$

$16=2^3+2^3$

$17=3^2+2^2+2^2$

$18=3^2+3^2$

$20=2^3+2^3+2^2$

$21=2^3+3^2+2^2$

$24=2^3+2^3+2^3$

and it seems every number $\ge 24$ is also representable as a sum of perfect powers (I checked up to 1000 using computer).

Is this known?

Any ideas how to prove it?

Comment: Well, if you allow repeated perfect powers, what restrictions are there on those powers?  Because otherwise, $2^0 = 1$, and you can just add a bunch of those.  Does the exponent have to be $\geq 2$?

Comment: Write your number in base $2$.  That gives you distinct perfect powers!

Comment: I don't want powers of $1$ in this representation

Comment: Ok.  If $n$ is even, then the base $2$ description works.  If $n$ is odd and bigger than $9$, then apply the base $2$ description to $n-3^2$.

Comment: Note:  since you also have to avoid $2^1=2$ in the sum, my comment needs some fleshing out.  I have posted details below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a different direction from orlp's answer (now deleted): It seems you allow repeated powers.  Assuming that exponents are required to be greater than or equal to $2$, observe that $2^2 = 4$ and $3^2 = 9$, and the Chicken McNuggets problem with $4$ and $9$ yields an upper bound of $4 \times 9 - 4 - 9 = 23$ for the numbers that cannot be expressed as a combination of those two numbers alone.

ETA: All other perfect powers of larger primes are $25$ or greater and therefore do not bear on this upper bound.

Comment: I haven't heard of Chicken McNuggets problem, I will check what it is

Comment: @tong_nor: It is also known as the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way that works for $n≥54$.

Writing the number in base $2$ gives such a sum, though of course $2^0=1$, or $2^1=2$ might appear.

If the number is divisible by $4$, then neither $2^0$ nor $2^1$  appears so we are done.

If the number is $1\pmod 4$ and at least $9$ then subtract $3^2=9$.

If the number is $3\pmod 4$ and at least $27$ then subtract $3^3$.

If the number is even but not divisible by $4$ then it is twice an odd number so we can reduce to that case.

In this way we are done if $n≥54$.  Case by case analysis handles most lower $n$ as well.

Comment: thanks for your approach also